# Add dynamic links in WordPress custom theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, links

I want to implement a system to insert custom links in my wordpress custom theme. I don't want to hardcode these links inside my theme. These links are for the socials or partners website. So they need to be easily changed from WordPress dashboard. I want to avoid registering a custom post type or using a post. Is this possible with a custom function or a similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ and create a custom field for the links.  Then use the value in the template. The ACF web site has some great documentation and examples.

Comment: Is there also a solution without using plugins?

Comment: @Yikko Yes, you can use the custom fields option in the top bar of the WordPress page admin section. her is a link to the add_meta_box() that you will need to use in your template.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/  There is also a good tutorial on Sitepoint https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways of adding dynamic links to your theme. For example,

1. [Theme Customization API / Customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)
2. [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)
3. [Navigation menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)
4. [Links manager](https://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager) (maybe outdated?)
5. If the links are shown on a certain page (template), then maybe a [custom meta box](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/)